# Said to be made in China

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I'm looking for two words.

---

[image]

---

In this order:
**Y** **B** **R**

|-2 -13 +2|+3 -12 -2 -1|+7 -8 +4 +0|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two words you are looking for are:

> Magic Square

Because:

> The three by three grid is a magic square, where each number has been replaced by its initial letter, and an ordinal representing its position in the list of numbers starting with that letter (so 1 = o1, 2 = t1, 3 = t2, 4 = f1 etc.)
>
> ```
>  2   7   6
>  9   5   1
>  4   3   8
>  =
>  t1  s2  s1
>  n1  f2  o1
>  f1  t2  e1
> ```
>
> And the image on the right is a hint, with "f4" (=15) at the top, and lines representing the directions that the magic square sums to 15.
>
> So that gives us Y=o1=ONE, B=f1=FOUR and R=n1=NINE.
>
> And the final line represents a letter shifts on each word in that order (so ONE with |-2-13+2| gives us O-2=M, N-13=A, E+2=G):
>
> |MAG|ICSQ|UARE|
>
> And for the title, magic squares were first invented/discovered (or at least first documented) in China.

Comment: Nice and quick :) Well done!